# Features of GStreamer

Tags: streaming, gstreamer

Does GStreamer have the following functionalities/features, or is it possible to implement them on top of GStreamer:

- Time windows: set up the graph such that a sink pad of one element does not just receive the current frame, but also `n` previous frames and `m` future frames. Including when seeking to a new position.
- No data copies when passing data between elements, instead reusing the same buffer.
- Having shared data between mutiple elements on different branches, that changes with time, but is buffered in such a way that all elements get the same value for it for the same frame index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1) Time windows**

You need to write your plugin using [GstAdapter](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstAdapter.html).

**Q2) No data copies when passing data between elements**

It's done by default.  No data is copied from element to element unless required.  It just passes a pointer to an instance of GstBuffer.  If an element is like encoder or filter, which needs to work on a buffer to *produce* new data, a new GstBuffer instance is created with newly generated data in GstMemory, obviously.

**Q3) Having shared data between mutiple elements**

Not sure exactly what you mean.  Is is possible to achieve what you want by using GstMemory share?  Take a look at [gst_memory_share()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstMemory.html#gst-memory-share), [gst_buffer_copy_region()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBuffer.html#gst-buffer-copy-region), or [gst_adapter_get_buffer()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstAdapter.html#gst-adapter-get-buffer).